# how to build maven dependencies into jar and pack it into a war file

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies, war

In my maven project, i wanted to build all java source code into one jar (rtcc.jar) and all maven dependencies into another jar (external-lib.jar) and finally pack both these jars into a war file (rtccClient.war). rtcc.jar gets generated properly but jar with dependencies (external-lib) is not getting generated. .Below is my pom.xml. Please update where i am doing mistake.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>            
        </plugin>       
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>                     
                    <id>default-jar</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>

                        </archive>
                        <finalName>rtccJar/lib/rtcc</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
         <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <classifier>only-library</classifier>
        <excludes>
          <exclude&>**/Main*</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <finalName>rtccJar/lib/external-lib</finalName>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>

        <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib/lib</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>sign</id>                       
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sign</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>                 
                <archiveDirectory>${basedir}/target/rtccJar/lib</archiveDirectory>
                <archiveDirectory>${basedir}/target/lib/lib</archiveDirectory>
                <includes>                      
                    <include>rtcc.jar</include>
                    <include>vcsireader1-1.1.jar</include>
                    <include>vcsutil1-1.1.jar</include>
                    <include>yaml1-1.1.jar</include>
                    <include>yamldefs1-1.1.jar</include>
                    </includes>
                <keystore>${basedir}/extFiles/jarSigner/jarsignercert2.p12</keystore>
                <alias>jarsigner</alias>
                <storepass>scarbo</storepass>
                <keypass>mykpass</keypass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
            <webResources>
                <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/target/rtccJar</directory>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/target/lib/lib</directory>
                         <includes>
                                <include>vcsireader1-1.1.jar</include>
                                <include>vcsutil1-1.1.jar</include>
                                <include>yaml1-1.1.jar</include>
                                <include>yamldefs1-1.1.jar</include>
                           </includes>
                           <targetPath>lib</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/extFiles/extlib</directory>
                    </resource>
                    </webResources>
                <packagingExcludes>**/com/**</packagingExcludes>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <warName> ${artifactId} </warName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: There are already plenty of examples out there and more than enough solutions on SO. this is a duplicate...

Comment: Why do you want that? Why not just pack all jars into the war as usual?